# How to make Form with 'option' from database query - I`m beginner

Tags: php, forms

my goal is to scan database for tables, then to put this table names to "option" in html form. And finally I want to get selected option to $_POST .

Now i have this:

```
    <form action='choosetable.php' method='POST'>
    <select>
    <?php 
    $table_array= array([0] => $table);
    $result = $choosetable->query("SHOW TABLES");
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() ){
    $table = $row[0];
    ?>
  <option><?echo '<h3>',$table,'</h3>';?> <!-- выяснить про '<h3>',$table,'</h3>'-->
 </option>
<?};?>
</select>
</form>
```

It partally works but i don`t know how to assign option name"" for user selected option ??

Please help me!!

Comment: Thank you friend! You`ve really helped me! Now all works! I thought about to put same "$table" in value, but I was afraid that during cycle $table in value will be changed/updated after iteration. I should discover more about cycles. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [`option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) with no `value` attribute will have no value to send. Update your HTML to:

```
<option value="<?php echo $table;?>"><h3><?php echo $table;?></h3></option>
```

Additionally your [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) also needs a `name` attribute, otherwise it will not be accessible by PHP.

```
<select name="table">
```

Also when you use this in value in your SQL make sure you are using it against a whitelist, don't just pass it to your query or you will be open to SQL injections. Prepared statements/parameterized queries can't be used to prevent an injection here because they are only for values, not identifiers.